# akka tcp example freezes on connection

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I have written out [this akka tcp example](http://hseeberger.github.io/blog/2013/06/17/introduction-to-akka-i-slash-o/), which is very close to the official example but it was more hand-holdy.

I didn't make an sbt or dependencies file since I assumed IntelliJ completed those for me given I have all the right references and libraries from maven.

I wrote the example in IntelliJ, when I run it everything seems to work but when I telnet from CMD to the server telnet just holds on `connecting to 127.0.0.1`

Then when I close the terminal it says in the server log

`[INFO] [04/04/2015 12:02:43.207] [System-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://System/user/Server/$a] Message [akka.dispatch.sysmsg.DeathWatchNotification] from Actor[akka://System/user/Server/$a#1949766491] to Actor[akka://System/user/Server/$a#1949766491] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.`

I figure im not handling the case for this message which is fine but the fact that telnet just freezes when this would insinuate that there was a connection of some kind is just frustrating.

Given that this example works for other people, I don't mean for people to debug the code, with that being said is there somthing wrong with telnet on windows or something similar that is wrong?

Comment: This question says “please debug my code for me” without showing any of the code; I might be wrong but I think stackoverflow is not the platform for this kind of question.

Comment: I don't mean it that way, I would just like to know if the example is being used incorrectly, like if there is any known problems with using TCP on windows, or of running it through IntelliJ breaks the code, or if I need to do something with firewalls, stuff like that. Can I reword it to sound not debug code plzx (especially given its code that works for other people)

Comment: I solved the issue anyway

Comment: I'm glad that you found your solution! I hope that you can see that with the information contained in the question nobody could have helped you. Next time please try to be more precise when asking and include all the available information; it is not unusual to realize the solution while properly formulating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is an interesting combination.

Firstly none of the tutorials were hand holdy enough to mention a need to set the loglevel in the file application.conf

application.conf:

```
akka {
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

Without the loglevel set the log.debug statements never show by default which is what would have made debugging way easier(funny that)

Secondly telnet on windows (in it's default configuration anyway) only seems to let you send one character press at a time which is very odd resulting in a single character packet. The part that threw me for a loop is that telnet, rather than writing on a new line something like "PACKET RECEIVED: a", just put the echoed 'a' on the same line as the keypress resulting in

`aa`

in the terminal every time 'a' was pressed leading me to believe there was an issue when there really wasn't